# Xamarin Forms WinPhone - How to make Label Text Underline WinPhone?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, win-phone-silverlight-8.1, xamarin.winphone

How can I make **Label** text **Underline** in **WinPhone** using **Xamarin Forms** ?

Comment: Create renderer for `Label` and use native **WinPhone** approach for creating underlined text.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ExtendedLabel) sample?

Comment: Yes @EgorGromadskiy but i cant find **ExtendedLabelRenderer** for WinPhone in this [github repo](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ExtendedLabel#platform-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using following xaml;

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label Text="SomeText"/>
    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Black"/>
</StackLayout>
```

this should do it for all 3 platforms. :)

Comment: This merely draws a box view with height 1 and has nothing to do with underline. It would break when your label text is shorter or you specify alignment and when it goes into 2 lines.

Comment: I have the same implementation with a data trigger on text property length and this provides me a google material design entry. I'm happy with it till now. :)

Comment: As @RohitVipinMathews said, this is really just a hacky workaround and would potentially have issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have top create a new control in your PCL/shared project inheriting from Label.

```
public class Exlabel : Label
{
}
```

In your windows phone project create a [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer) for it as follows and use the [TextBlock.TextDecorations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textdecorations(v=vs.110).aspx) Property to set the underline. 
The label is rendered as [TextBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(v=vs.110).aspx) in windows.

Sample (*untested*):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Exlabel), typeof(ExlabelRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.WinPhone81
{
    public class ExlabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.UnderLine;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using the windows phone check out this sample - [How to format texts of TextBlock using xaml in Windows Phone](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/734527/How-to-format-texts-of-TextBlock-using-xaml-in-W).

For WinRT you can use this - [TextBlock underline in WinRT](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/915740e9-a693-40b9-96a4-07d2784d3b53/textblock-underline-in-winrt?forum=winappswithcsharp).

In SilverLight WinPhone (the old and not so supported template), you can also use the Margin to achieve what you require, similar to [How to make an underlined input text field in Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587340/how-to-make-an-underlined-input-text-field-in-windows-phone).

Comment: I can't find this property ! I have this error :
Error CS1061 'TextBlock' does not contain a definition for 'TextDecorations' and no extension method 'TextDecorations' accepting a first argument of type 'TextBlock' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is the type you are getting for `Control` in Windows phone project?

Comment: Are you missing the namespace, its available in the link provided. `System.Windows.Controls`. Please try to resolve compile time errors.

Comment: I talk about **Xamarin WinPhone**, i can't use `System.Windows.Controls`, but we talk about `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls`, [See this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209652)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a custom view for this as a Layout/Grid that has a Label and a BoxView with a small heightRequest below the label to act as a line.

Comment: Yes i can't find another solution

Answer (score 0):

Create a label renderer in your WinPhone project:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedLabel), typeof(ExtendedLabelRenderer))]

namespace SampleProject.WinPhone
{
public class ExtendedLabelRenderer: LabelRenderer
{
    ExtendedLabel element;
    TextBlock control;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if((ExtendedLabel)Element == null || Control == null)
            return;

        element = (ExtendedLabel)Element;
        control = Control;
        UnderlineText();
    }
    void UnderlineText()
    {
        control.Text = string.Empty;
        Underline ul = new Underline();
        Run run = new Run();
        run.Text = element.Text;
        ul.Inlines.Add(run);
        control.Inlines.Add(ul);
    }
  }
 }
```